# multiplayer cardgame - start child process or handle in one process

Tags: node.js

So Im learning node.js and making a random player vs player cardgame. I will be using sockets and sessions.

Theoreticall ill have lots of games running at the same time.

Whats the best practice here, do I spawn a child process of my node server for every game, or simply just keep data of ongoing games and 'boards' in the main server and just grab a given game every time there is an action?

Comment: Short answer: the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming there's no intensive CPU processing going on, you should do it all in a single process. Node is very good at doing a high volume of very small operations very quickly, all on a single thread, and it sounds like that fits your application.

If you were going to be doing CPU-intensive calculations you might want to hand off to worker processes, but you still wouldn't want a separate process per game.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, you'll want to load balance however many servers you need.  If you're using socket.io, then you should look into socket.io-redis ([briefly covered here](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/#passing-events-between-nodes)) to see how you can have connections running across multiple servers still talk to each other.  With an approach like this, you'll need to consider the fact that you can't store some info in memory, and instead will need to persist to redis or a similarly accessible medium for all servers to access.

Comment: In other words, one process per node, but the ability to scale out by adding nodes.  OP is asking about spawning a node process per game, which is um, probably not advisable.